# How to perfom BLE over-the-air firmware update through android app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ota

I am trying to develop an android application to communicate with BLE device. I am able to read and write characteristics to/from BLE device. Now I want to perform ble OTA update for the device through my app. I don't know how to do? If I have the OTA update file how can I install it on the ble device and how to perfom OTA upgrade?

Comment: What is the remote BLE device that you are trying to perform the OTA update on?

Comment: Iam using dialog semiconductor

Comment: @YoussifSaeed Can you please tell me how to update that device using my app.

Comment: No idea, I was hoping that you are using one of Nordic's devices who have a lot of source code and documentation for their OTA. Your best bet is to check if dialog offer the source code for their Android apps. Please see this: https://support.dialog-semiconductor.com/ota-update-apps-now-available.

Comment: @YoussifSaeed Ok. I will check. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from File using

```
protected byte[] readFile(File file) {
    BufferedInputStream buf;
    int size = (int) file.length();
    byte[] mDataFile = new byte[size];
    //mDataFile = new byte[size];
    try {
        buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        buf.read(mDataFile, 0, size);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mDataFile;
}
```

Then, start the device scan . After the device got connected using particular macAddress 
call the method connectToDevice

```
public static BluetoothGatt connectToDevice(Context context,
                                   BluetoothDevice device,
                                   BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallBack){
    BluetoothGatt connectedGatt = null;
    if (device != null) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            connectedGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false,
                    mGattCallBack,
                    BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE,
                    BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_2M|BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_1M);
        }else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            connectedGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, mGattCallBack, BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE);
        } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            connectedGatt = connectGattApi21(context, device, mGattCallBack);
        } else {
            connectedGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false,
                    mGattCallBack);
        }
    } else {
        //WiSeSdkFileWritter.writeToFile(fileName, TAG + " FAILED could not find remote device/ remote device is null >>" + macAddress);
    }
    return connectedGatt;
}
```

then handle the BluetoothGattCallback callback methods - onServicesDiscovered,onCharacteristicWrite,onConnectionStateChange

In onServicesDiscovered method you will get the BluetoothGattService. From the gattService , extract the characteristics . finally write the characteristics to the ble device.

```
     BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

    BluetoothGattService mService = gatt.getService(service);

        mCharacteristics = mService.getCharacteristic(characteristics);
        mCharacteristics.setValue(bytes);


        Logger.v(TAG, "data write count  ::" + writeCounter++);

        Timer t = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                gatt.writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristics);
            }
        }; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
    }
};
```

Comment: I have done the ble characteristics reading and writing but I don't know how to use them for OTA upgrade

Comment: I just read characteristics and services from the device like battery service. But now I want OTA updation. But I don't know how to do it in my code